# Onclick is not working when use that as object

Tags: javascript

This is works fine when i am using `addEventListener`. But, it is not working when i use `button.click` . what is the mistake on the below code? what is the cause it is not working on `varNext.click= myFunc;`?

[code]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Slideshow</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = ['home_default.png','about_default.png','blog_default.png','logo.png'];
function myFunc(){

var var1 = document.getElementById("slideimage");
var var2 = var1.name.split("_");
//alert(var2);
index = var2[1];

if(index == images.length - 1){
index = 0;
}else {index++;}

var1.name = "image_" + index;
var1.src = images[index];
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><img id="slideimage" name="image_0" src="home_default.png" alt="Home"></p>
<form name="slideform">
<input type="button" id="nextbtn" value="Next">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var varNext = document.getElementById("nextbtn");
//varNext.addEventListener("click", myFunc, false);
varNext.click= myFunc;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[/code]

Comment: [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) is a method, which triggers click event, you need `varNext.onclick = ...` instead, or rather just keep using `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than [`.click`<sup>fires the element's click event</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) it must be [`.onclick`<sup>property returns the onClick event handler</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick)

*Try this*

```
varNext.onclick = myFunc;
```

***[`Demo Fiddle of your code`](http://jsfiddle.net/RpHA8/)***

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the onclick attribute

```
varNext.onclick = myFunc;
```